# Can't login anymore onto my Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I've tried to change the shell for my root user. When I login now with my no-rights user and try to switch to my root users with `su root -> password`, the login fails because of this message:

```
Cannot execute whereis zsh: No such file or directory
```

The problem is, that I've entered the wrong path during the shell change to zsh. Any idea how I can fix this so I can log back in?

Comment: can you add more detail ? like what you used to change the shell ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu has `sudo` installed by default.  If you still have sudo access you should be able to

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
```

This will reset root's shell to bash.  Try this first.

If you don't have sudo access then you need to find a way to edit `/etc/passwd`.  You might need to boot your system with special options giving you a root shell, OR you could plug your disk drive into another machine.

---

If you really need the root shell, there's instructions here: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/09/02/reset-forgotten-passwords-ubuntu-16-04/

At boot you either:

- Select `Advanced option for Ubuntu` --> `Ubuntu .... (Recovery Mode)` --> `root - Drop to root shell prompt`
- OR... press `e` while `Ubuntu` is selected and add the text `init=/bin/bash` to the linux params